# Restrict login between two websites with same domain

Tags: authentication, .net

I have two websites *[www.abc.com/de-de](http://www.abc.com/de-de)* and *[www.abc.com/es-es](http://www.abc.com/es-es)* . if the user logs into the first website then he is automatically logged into the second website as the domain is same. how can I avoid this? I am using `Sitecore.Security.Authentication` for authentication